# .Net Core (Visual Studio Mac) Cannot add Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I am using Visual Studio for Mac that was recently released. I can create a simple MVC web app but I am having issues Adding entity framework.

I use the Manage Nuget packages and choose EntityFramework. It runs through a bunch of retrieving package statements and finally fails with a reference to OpenSSL which I thought I had installed properly.

I am sure I am missing something simple here but I am struggling to figure out what it is.

All I want is a simple MVC web app that I can connect using EF to an Azure DB

```
Retrieving package 'System.Threading 4.3.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'System.Threading.Tasks 4.3.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.3.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'System.Threading.Timer 4.3.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'System.Xml.ReaderWriter 4.3.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'System.Xml.XDocument 4.3.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Adding package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0' to folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0' to folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0' to 'packages.config'
  OK https://api.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.1.1.0-preview4-final.nupkg 1146ms
Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.1.0-preview4-final.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0' to LighthouseFSQ
Adding package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets.1.1.0' to folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets.1.1.0' to folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Added package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets.1.1.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0' to LighthouseFSQ
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.0' does not exist in project 'LighthouseFSQ'*
Removed package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets.1.1.0' from 'packages.config'
Removed package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0' from 'packages.config'
Package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.0' does not exist in folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Removing package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets.1.1.0' from folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Removed package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets.1.1.0' from folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Removing package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0' from folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Removed package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.1.1.0' from folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Executing nuget actions took 4.14 sec
One or more errors occurred.
  Could not install package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
PM> Install-Package runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.1' with respect to project 'LighthouseFSQ', targeting '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1'
Gathering dependency information took 1.63 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.1'
Retrieving package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1' from 'nuget.org'.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/packages/runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.system.security.cryptography.openssl.4.3.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/packages/runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.system.security.cryptography.openssl.4.3.1.nupkg 122ms
Installing runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.1' does not exist in project 'LighthouseFSQ'
Package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.4.3.1' does not exist in folder '/Users/jragsdale/Projects/LighthouseFSQ/packages'
Executing nuget actions took 510.64 ms
One or more errors occurred.
  Could not install package 'runtime.debian.8-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl 4.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/ Clearly it has 1.1.1 official release. Why do you try to install a preview?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem updating the .net core target to 1.6 version (right click on project and goto Options->Build->General->TargetFramework) after that, installing the runtime.osx.10.10-x64.runtime.native.System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl nuget package.

I hope helps